# how to use method 1 variale in method 2

Tags: python

I am new to python and new to programming. I have question how can I use variables from method1 in method too.

Example

```
 class abc(self):
        def method1 (self,v1):
           v1 = a+b
             return v1 # want to use this value in method 2
        def method2(self)
               v2 * v1 = v3
```

Thanks

Comment: `v2 * v1 = v3` should raise a `SyntaxError`. Also, the `v1` argument to `method1` is ignored.

Comment: What tutorial are you using to learn programming?  Please **update** the question with the name or the link to the tutorial you're using.

Comment: No, I have not been reading any books just watching online tutorials but now I have started reading Programming for Non Programmers ...by steven F. Lott :)

Answer (score 1):

let `method2` "know" it is waiting for an argument:

```
def method2(self,v1): #note v1 was added here
   v2 * v1 = v3 #what does that suppse to do? [look my "third note"]
```

also note: you also need to pass `v2` to `method2()`

third note: what exactly are you trying to do in `v2 * v1 = v3` ? maybe you meant `v3 = v1 * v2` ?

Answer (score 1):

Make `v1` an instance variable by using `self`, i.e. `self.v1 = a+b` and `v2 * self.v1 = v3`. But that second command should look like this: `v3  = v2 * self.v1`. And there is still a problem in `v2` not being defined.

Note that with this approach, `method1` must be called before `method2`, otherwise `self.v1` will not be defined during processing of method2 (and it has to be). The approach of amit is cleaner.

Good luck in learning python. It is a great language.

Comment: Stuff on `self` is **not** a class variable. It's an instance variable. Class variables are attached to the class object and thus shared between all instances - rarer, but also useful.

Answer (score 0):

To use a value throughout a class, you need to bind that value to an attribute of its instance.

For example:

```
class Abc(object):     # put object here, not self

    def method1(self):
        self.v1 = 3 + 7  # now v1 is an attribute

    def method2(self)
        return 4 * self.v1

a = Abc()
a.method1()
a.v1   # -> 10
a.method2()  # -> 40
```

But usually is not a good practice to have an attribute rising after the call of some method, so you should also provide a default value for v1. Placing it in  `__init__`:

```
class Abc(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.v1 = 0

    def method1(self):
        self.v1 = 3 + 7

    def method2(self)
        return 4 * self.v1

a = Abc()
a.v1  # -> 0
a.method1()
a.v1   # -> 10
a.method2()  # -> 40
```

Comment: just for understanding > if use self.v1 (make it attribute of instance methosd1) I can access access self.v1 anywhere inside the calls even in method3 or method4
what is difference between self.v1 and v1

Comment: @Shazib: Yes, you can also use it in other methods. `v1` is a variable and its scope dies at the end of the method, `self.v1` is like calling `a.v1` inside your method so it's an attribute of `a` (an instance of `Abc`). You can learn more about it in [Attributes and Methods](http://www.cafepy.com/article/python_attributes_and_methods/contents.html).

Answer (score 0):

one more way is to use global variable.

```
def a():
    global v
    v = 10;

def b():
    print v

if __name__=='__main__':
    a()
    b()
```

Comment: Please no, don't use global here. Also you don't declare `v` at the beginning. Use global only if you **need** to.